# Installing PyQT5 on Ubuntu16.04

Tags: python, pyqt5, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to install python-pyqt5 in my PC with Ubuntu16.04.

When I install like

```
sudo apt install python-pyqt5
```

The system said, it is already installed.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-pyqt5 is already the newest version (5.5.1+dfsg-3ubuntu4).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libbotan-1.10-1 libclang1-3.6 libllvm3.6v5 libobjc-5-dev libobjc4
  libqbscore1 libqbsqtprofilesetup1 libqt4-designer libqt4-help libqt4-opengl
  libqt4-scripttools libqt4-svg libqt4-test libqt5concurrent5
  libqt5designercomponents5 libqt5quickwidgets5 libqt5script5
  libqt5xmlpatterns5 libqtassistantclient4 libqtwebkit4
  linux-headers-4.15.0-34 linux-headers-4.15.0-34-generic
  linux-image-4.15.0-34-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-34-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-34-generic python-qt4 qml-module-qtquick-controls
  qtbase5-dev-tools qtcreator-data qtcreator-doc qttools5-dev-tools
  qtxmlpatterns5-dev-tools
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
```

But when I check wheather I have PyQt5

```
>>from PyQt5.Qt import PYQT_VERSION_STR
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named PyQt5.Qt
```

The system said, I have no module for PyQt5.

How to install PyQt5 and QtCreator in my Ubuntu16.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu has Python2 and 3. Modules are different for either version.

Try installing pip and list modules to see if it exists in either installation.
If you're using Python2:

```
sudo apt install python-pip
pip list
```

For Python3:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
pip3 list
```

If you wish to install through pip you can just do 'pip install PyQt' or 'pip3 install PyQt'.

Comment: My problem is I can't install, the system says it has pyqt. But when I check the version it has, error is `No module named PyQt5.Qt`

Comment: I do `locate PyQt5` and it shows `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyQt5`, but I go to that folder, there is no PyQt5.

Comment: When I install pyqt5, it says `python-pyqt5 is already the newest version (5.5.1+dfsg-3ubuntu4).`. But there is error as `No module named PyQt5.Qt`, when I check the version.

Comment: Try pip/pip3 install --upgrade --force-reinstall pyqt5.